# Order LINQ result with match first

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var term = "ata";
var list = Cache.GetReferenceList<T>()
             .Where(x => x.AirportCode == term || x.AirportName.Contains(term))
             .Take(5).Select(z => new AirportResult
             {
                 ID = z.AirportId,
                 label = z.AirportCode + " - " + z.AirportName
             })
             .ToList();
```

If this returns me a list where the labels looks like so:

1. "ACV - Arcata"
2. "AMI - Matarami"
3. "ATA - Anta"

How can I order the list (using an OrderBy) so the match of the search term and AirportCode is at the top, followed by the others sorted by AirportCode? The result I am after would look like this:

1. "ATA - Anta"
2. "ACV - Arcata"
3. "AMI - Matarami"

Comment: @TML That's actually different - there is no null involved here

Comment: I misread, vote retracted. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `OrderBy` using a boolean:

```
var list = Cache.GetReferenceList<T>()
         .Where(x => x.AirportCode == term || x.AirportName.Contains(term))
         .OrderBy(x => x.AirportCode != term) // False is listed first
         .ThenBy(x => x.AirportName)
         .Take(5).Select(z => new AirportResult
         {
             ID = z.AirportId,
             label = z.AiportCode + " - " + z.AiportName
         })
         .ToList();
```